# Capistrano 3 - access denied to git repository on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, capistrano, bitbucket

I wanted to try the newer version of Capistrano 3 on a new project and have been struggling with this problem for a few days now.

while running "**cap production deploy**" for the first time, I always got the same error (LOG : http://pastebin.com/DKvzRTc2).

Apparently, it fails to run this command "git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:......" on the server

I've tried everything :
- forward_agent set as true with ssh key on local machine and uploaded on bitbucket
- forward_agent set as false and uploaded manually the ssh key on the production server (when I run manually 'git ls-remote@bitbucket.org:......' on the server, it works perfectly.

I've already set the "user" attribute on the deploy.rb file, this doesn't fix the issue.

Thanks for the help, I'm open to any suggestion!

Comment: I precise that I'm using Rails 4.0.1 and ruby 2.0.0p247 and capistrano 3.0.1

Comment: Still waiting for my savior :(

Comment: Also, the server is from linode, it's an Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To those who has the same problem, my solution was to delete all the SSH keys from the ssh-agent (ssh-add -d path/to/all/keys) and then re-add your key (ssh-add yourkey).

I have no idea why but it seems that Capistrano 3 only consider the first key of your ssh-agent and use that key to access your git repository.

Hence, if your first key is not your project SSH key, then it will throw the exception error.

I didn't find any other way to fix it.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it for me after hours of trial and error. Also if you use "ssh-add -D" (notice the capital D) you dont have to supply the path.

Comment: " ssh-add -D " really helped a lot If you have more than ssh-keys added to ssh-agent

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It turned out it was trying to run scripts from /tmp.
I did not have execute permissions in the /tmp directory. I added

> set :tmp_dir, '/home/_user_home_dir/tmp'

to the staging.rb file.

It ran no problems.